# Redirection to another port on the same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a web application in `http://example.com:8080/example-app/`

When the user types `http://example.com/` , I'd like to redirect him to the web app.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   (.*)example.com$         [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:8080/example-app/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I believe the .htaccess has the correct access right:

```
$ ls -altr /var/www/html/.htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 178 Jul  2 00:31 /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

But navigating to http://example.com/ just serves the index.html file.

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?
I there a way to debug this? (apache on centos).

Comment: I had a problem with apache configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

change the server default listening port from 8080 to 80 in configuration file
this one is easy 
or 
try the proxy tho redirect the request as below and the default Document
Root folder

```
     NameVirtualHost *:8080

    <VirtualHost *>
     ServerAdmin me@example.com
     ServerName www.example.com:8080
     ProxyPreserveHost On

  # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       </Proxy>
     ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:80/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:80/
   </VirtualHost>
```